# Probability confusion with binomial coefficient

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A manufactorer claims that poor quality of supplies yields 70% of defected TVs. Find the probability that 5 of the next 6 TVs will be defective to the poor quality of supplies.

The answer is $$\binom{6}{5}(0.7)^5 (0.3)^1 = 0.3025$$

I don't understand why that is. We choose 5 of the 6 TVs (without order), then multiply by the chance they may be defective. Why multiply by the chance a TV is not defective?

Comment: given your comments to the answers, you should accept one of them. By other hand, if you think both were helpful, you should also upvote them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that an individual TV is defective is $0.7$ (hence the probability that it's ok is $0.3$).

The probability that, from a set of $6$ TVs, the first 5 are defective and the last one is ok, is then $0.7 \times 0.7 \times 0.7 \times 0.7 \times 0.7 \times 0.3 = 0.7^5 0.3^1$

The probability that any $5$ of them are defective (and the remaining one is ok) is the same number, multiplied by all the ways of selecting $5$ elements from a set of $6$, i.e, $C_{6,5}$

Comment: Ah thank you! Your answer as well as Eric's help this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is the probability that *exactly* 5 of the 6 are defective.  That means 5 of them are defective, and 1 isn't.  Given any 5 particular TVs, there is a $(0.7)^5$ chance that those $5$ are defective, and a $(0.3)^1$ chance that the last 1 is not defective.  There are $\binom{6}{5}$ different ways to choose 5 of the 6 TVs.  So in total, you get that the probability is $\binom{6}{5}(0.7)^5(0.3)^1$.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Eric. This makes a lot of sense. I